# How to create a Role with execute() keeping it safe from sql injection?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want my python app admin to be able to create a role in postgreSQL in it's interface.
I made this method :

```
 def creer_user(self,login,pwd,groupe):
        queryrole = "CREATE ROLE %s WITH PASSWORD %s LOGIN NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE INHERIT NOREPLICATION CONNECTION LIMIT -1;"
        self.cursor.execute(queryrole,(login,pwd))

        querygrant = f"GRANT '{G.APP}', %s TO %s;"
        self.cursor.execute(querygrant,(groupe,login))
```

But it's not working because the parameters in execute() wrap my strings like *'rolename'*.
And I read it need to be *"rolename"* or *rolename*

I can do this :

```
queryrole = f"CREATE ROLE "{login}" WITH PASSWORD %s LOGIN NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE INHERIT NOREPLICATION CONNECTION LIMIT -1;"
        self.cursor.execute(queryrole,(pwd,))
```

But I believe it's not SQL injection safe.

Is there a simple solution ?

Comment: Use quote_ident(): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

Comment: Doesnt seem to work in this case :

_Exception has occurred: SyntaxError
ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « ( »
LINE 1: CREATE ROLE quote_ident('test') WITH PASSWORD...._

Comment: You first have to create a safe piece of SQL, just like Laurens Albe did, and then you can execute this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `format()` in SQL:

```
format(
   'CREATE ROLE %I WITH PASSWORD %L LOGIN NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE INHERIT NOREPLICATION CONNECTION LIMIT -1',
   'rolenane',
   'password'
)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work inside cursor.execute().
My statement : 
`self.cursor.execute(f"FORMAT('CREATE ROLE %I WITH PASSWORD %L LOGIN NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE INHERIT NOREPLICATION CONNECTION LIMIT -1','{login}','{pwd}')")`
produce:
`Exception has occurred: SyntaxError
ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « FORMAT »
LINE 1: FORMAT('CREATE ROLE %I WITH PASSWORD %L LOGIN NOSUPERUSER NO...`

Comment: Adding `EXECUTE FORMAT(...` Also dont work

Comment: That only constructs the statement, it doesn't execute it. You'd run one query `SELECT format(...)`, and send the result as a second query.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Found a way to do it using `cursor.mogrify()`, and formating the **'** as **"** in the resulting string.
Not really elegant. But I believe it's at least SQL injection proof.

```
query = self.cursor.mogrify("CREATE ROLE %s WITH PASSWORD %s LOGIN NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE INHERIT NOREPLICATION CONNECTION LIMIT -1;",(login,pwd))
## mogrify generate bynary code, so we need to convert it.
query_format = query.decode('utf-8').replace(f"'{login}'",f"\"{login}\"")
self.cursor.execute(query_format)
```